# Disable Command-C and -V in Cocoa Mac App

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos-carbon

I'd like to disable certain keyboard shortcuts while my App is running, preferably even when it enters the background. I've read about disabling all shortcuts using some old Carbon commands

```
void *oldHotKeyMode = PushSymbolicHotKeyMode(kHIHotKeyModeAllDisabled);
```

Unfortunately this disables all keyboard shortcuts which I don't want to do. How can I 'target' specific key pairs. It would be really cool if I could remap those commands to a specific method so I can display a "You can't copy this" message or something along those lines.

Comment: if nothing in your responder chain responds to copy: then it will be disabled in the menu... you can just remove the copy menu item... I think that is what catches the keyboard shortcut usually... if you use text views and text fields you may have to subclass them

Comment: I don't have a menu. My App is a status bar only app. I'm still having the problem

Comment: the simplest thing I can think of would be subclassing the fields and views that are responding to copy: to make it a noop

Comment: Any luck with a solution?

Comment: @Sunkas I could override almost anything by changing the preferences via applescript at startup. Unfortunately Copy and Paste were hardwired.

Comment: Ok, I just wanted to disable copying in PDFKit. But found that you could override the `copy` method :)